# How do I convert the Socket.IO chat example to run on the web?

Tags: heroku, socket.io, chat

For reference: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

The guide says that it's for localhost only:

> Socket.IO is composed of two parts:
>
> 1. A server that integrates with (or mounts on) the Node.JS HTTP Server:
>    socket.io
> 2. A client library that loads on the browser side: socket.io-client
>
> During development, socket.io serves the client
> automatically for us, as we’ll see, so for now we only have to install
> one module.

I've already completed the guide. It works in development. I now want to test this on Heroku (I already know how to deploy to Heroku). The guide seems to be telling me I need `socket.io-client` to do that, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `socket.io-client` had nothing to do with it. The example wouldn't work on Heroku because `process.env.PORT` wasn't being used. In `index.js` replace this:

```
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

with this:

```
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```